# PayPal Payment Review

Tags: paypal

We have had a few clients have orders marked as suspected fraud. I've read quite a lot of why this happens but what I'm more interested in is how the orders should be handled within Magento if the order isn't actually fraudulent.

It appear that when you update the order to complete via PayPal, it updates the order comments in Magento but then doesn't change the order state from payment review to processing. Is there a way you change the order state when it's in review?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I usually fix this in the database by running the following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE `sales_flat_order` SET state = 'processing', status = 'processing' WHERE state = 'payment_review' AND status = 'fraud'
```

Be careful, though, normally you should not use direct DB queries, so be sure to test this in a testing/staging environment first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there no way that a client could handle this via the admin (without writing something for them of course).

Comment: as far as I know is "Suspected fraud" a dead end. There is nothing one can do.